# Issue brush stroke with texture has different colour in Adobe Illustrator CC

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, brush

Yesterday I had some issue with Adobe Illustrator CC that didn't want to open, then I reinstalled it today.

But when I was going to make use of it, I noticed that brushes with custom textures (pencil texture) didn't appear to be as the same color that I chose, going slightly brighter as I wanted.

**Is it a misconfiguration of the software?**

**Can I fix it to the right color?**

(Top colors are the ones that I want. Bottom are the misconfigured?)

[image]

If anyone could help me with that, I'll be really happy.

Comment: maybe the brush has a color applied in it that modifies whatever color you choose for the new objects using it?

Comment: Actually not because before I uninstall AI, the pencil texture was solid black.

Comment: Hi John B,
Its not the misconfiguration of software. I think you by mistake changed your file colour mode from RGB to CMYK, change it back or create a new RGB colour profile document and Import your file. I hope this will solve your Issue.

Comment: @Rishab.Ag I noticed as soon I Saved of Web, I noticed a tab called Color Table and I set it to #000000 and the pencil got set as pitch black. Is there an option to change that before saving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is your issue but it might be what you mean:

Sometime brushes and artistic strokes in Illustrator have some transparency that can change the color slightly.

To fix this, you can select your artwork and use the "flatten transparency" in the Object Menu.

Then add your favorite color to this new shape.

[image]